# Conectar python con base de datos mysql en la nube

Tags: mysql, python

py que se ejecuta en mi pc y una base de datos en mi hosting. Como puedo hacer la conexión de dicha bd con el script .py?

Comment: Primero ver si tu hosting tiene abiertos los puertos de mysql (telnet tuhost puerto), si es afirmativo, solo cambia el host regularmente la ip y pon el nombre de tu host o la ip pública y listo.

Comment: Ahora me dice Access denied for user (using password: YES)

Comment: En la conexión de python ponle los datos que sean necesarios.
http://librosweb.es/libro/python/capitulo_12/conectarse_a_la_base_de_datos_y_ejecutar_consultas.html viene un ejemplo de conexión. Eso regularmente sucede por que tu servicio de hosting permite las conexiones a localhost de cualquier usuario pero de fuera existe más seguridad, para ello necesitaras ver en tu panel el usuario y contraseña que tenga tu servicio y adicionalmente que tenga el permiso de conectarse de cualquier IP.

Comment: Y una recomendación, mejor baja la base de datos de tu hosting a un servidor local (la instalación de Mysql no es nada complicada) y realiza todas tus pruebas localmente, si funciona localmente funcionará en producción, es mucho más seguro así.

Comment: Si ya pude realizar la conexión. Gracias

Comment: puedes poner que tuviste que hacer como una respuesta para que si a alguien más le llega a pasar tenga una orientación. Gracias.

Comment: Solo tuve que configurar en mi hosting. Dar permiso para acceder a la base de datos.